# How to rearrange the string in C#

Tags: streamreader

\In my csv file have two row data :
\a;b;c;d;e;
\1;2;3;4;5;
\How do I make it as below in c#:
\a=1;`enter code here`
\b=2;`enter code here`
\c=3;`enter code here`
\d=4;`enter code here`
\e=5;`enter code here`

Answer (score 0):

tldr; you split the text.

> 1. got string from csv  //e.g. string originalTxt  =  @"\a;b;c;d;e; \1;2;3;4;5";
> 2. split row
> 3. rearrange/edit for each word in each row
> 4. combine

```
string resultTxt = "";
string mycodehere ="enter code here ";
string originalTxt = ...; //TODO :: your code for get text from csv 
string[2] rows = originalTxt.Split('\');   // split the \ got 2 rows 
string[] row1 = rows[0].Split(';');    //split each word
string[] row2 = rows[1].Split(';');    //split each word
for(int i= 0 ; i< row1.Count ; i++){
     resultTxt  +=  @"\" + row1[i] + "=" + row2[i] + ";" + mycodehere + " " ; 
}
 //TODO :: use resultTxt
```